# How to add external modules and libraries to existing Android project in IntelliJ 13

Tags: android, intellij-idea, facebook-android-sdk, android-support-library, android-library

The libraries that I want to add for my existing project are;

- android-support-v4.jar
- FacebookSDK

I'll tell how I did it;

***Adding android-support-v4.jar***

- Up to date my Android SDK
- Navigate to *extras\android\support\v4* from Explorer
- Copy the *android-support-v4.jar* file and paste it inside my project *libs* directory on IntelliJ IDEA
- Select my module and open the *Project Structure* window
- Under *Project Settings* pane select *Modules* option
- From the middle pane, selected my module
- From right most pane, selected *Dependencies* tab and click on the plus-icon
- Select ***1 Jars and Directories***
- Navigate to *libs* directory of my project where I copied *android-support-v4.jar* and select it and press OK button

***Adding FacebookSDK***

- Select my module from Project window in IntelliJ and open Project Structure window
- Under *Project Settings* pane select *Modules* option
- Then on the top of the middle pane there is a plus-icon and selected it
- Selected ***Import Module*** from the drop down
- Navigate to *FacebookSDK* directory which I have downloaded and extracted and continue the *Import Module* wizard
- In that wizard I have **deselected** the *android-support-v4.jar* which is in *FacebookSDK/libs* directory because I have already included latest *android-support-v4.jar* above
- Finish the wizard but didn't close the *Project Structure* window because of following steps
- Again, under *Project Settings* pane select *Modules* option
- In the middle pane selected my module
- From the right hand pane under *Dependencies* tab click on the plus-icon
- Select ***3 Module Dependency*** from pop up
- From *Choose Module* window select *FacebookSDK* and press OK

After adding those two and click on the *Make Project* icon on IntelliJ, I am still getting following error

```
java: package android.support.v4.view does not exist
```

Where I made the mistake?

Comment: You should add android-support-v4.jar to facebook module again, in additional to add this to my module.